# Flash items won't display on Ipad

Tags: html, css, flash

I have a problem regarding the ipad. Here is the website that I am working on http://www.gmbelt.com/index.html, the problem is that the navigation bar down the side and the navigation buttons (at the top) and the banner in the middle are made in flash and the ipad doesn't support flash.

Is there anyway that I can recreate these items in html or css?

any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Here is the code I'm using.

PS I know it's not a good idea to create a website using tables but it's been done and I'm not changing the layout as there are loads of pages and it would take to long.

```
<html>

<head>
<meta name="GENERATOR" content="Microsoft FrontPage 5.0">
<meta name="ProgId" content="FrontPage.Editor.Document">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
<title>Home</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/stylesheet.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/stylesheet_css_buttons.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/stylesheet_zen_lightbox.css" />
</head>

<body bgcolor="#1B3917">

<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: collapse" bordercolor="#111111" width="100%" height="100%">
<tr>
<td width="100%">
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: collapse" bordercolor="#111111" width="100%" height="507">
<tr>
<td rowspan="2" height="175">&nbsp;</td>
<td width="1027" colspan="2" height="136">
<p align="center">
<img border="0" src="images/header.jpg" width="989" height="140"></td>
<td rowspan="2" height="175">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="1027" colspan="2" height="39">
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: collapse" width="100%">
<tr>
<td width="75"><SCRIPT src="displayFlashbutton_home.js"></SCRIPT></td>
<td width="75"><SCRIPT src="displayFlashbutton_contact.js"></SCRIPT></td>
<td width="75"><SCRIPT src="displayFlashbutton_about.js"></SCRIPT></td>
<td width="75%"><SCRIPT src="displayFlashbutton_downloads.js"></SCRIPT></td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td height="166" rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
<td width="150" height="166" rowspan="2">&nbsp;<SCRIPT src="displayFlashmenu.js"> </SCRIPT></td>
<td width="877" height="90" valign="top">
<p align="center">&nbsp;<SCRIPT src="displayFlashbanner.js"></SCRIPT></td>
<td height="166" rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<table border="1" bordercolor="#FFFFFF" height="100%" width="100%">
<tr>
<td align="center" width="100%" height="83" style="border:0">Please note, the home page is undergoing maintenance.<br><strong>However the menu and product items are fully working.</strong><br />We apologise for any inconvienice.<br />If you have any inquiries please contact Graham on 01455 271171 or <a href="mailto:graham@gmbelt.com">graham@gmbelt.com</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td height="150px" width="100%" style="border:0">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td height="150px" width="100%" style="border:0">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td height="150px" width="100%" style="border:0">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td height="166">&nbsp;</td>
<td width="150" height="166">&nbsp;</td>
<td width="877" height="166">
<p align="center">
<span style="color: rgb(170, 170, 170); font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 11px; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-weight: normal; letter-spacing: normal; line-height: normal; orphans: 2; text-align: center; text-indent: 0px; text-transform: none; white-space: normal; widows: 2; word-spacing: 0px; -webkit-text-size-adjust: auto; -webkit-text-stroke-width: 0px; background-color: rgb(27, 57, 22); display: inline !important; float: none; ">Copyright © 2012<span class="Apple-converted-space">&nbsp;</span></span><a href="http://www.gmbelt.com/index.html" target="_blank" style="color: rgb(153, 153, 153); text-decoration: none; font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 11px; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-weight: normal; letter-spacing: normal; line-height: normal; orphans: 2; text-align: center; text-indent: 0px; text-transform: none; white-space: normal; widows: 2; word-spacing: 0px; -webkit-text-size-adjust: auto; -webkit-text-stroke-width: 0px; background-color: rgb(27, 57, 22); ">Glen Esk Celtic and Highland Supplies<br></a>
<a class="mrk" href="http://www.thepcclinicuk.com/" target="_blank" style="color: rgb(153, 153, 153); text-decoration: none; background-color: rgb(27, 57, 22); font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 11px; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-weight: normal; letter-spacing: normal; line-height: normal; orphans: 2; text-align: center; text-indent: 0px; text-transform: none; white-space: normal; widows: 2; word-spacing: 0px; -webkit-text-size-adjust: auto; -webkit-text-stroke-width: 0px; ">Layout Design by The PC Clinic UK Ltd</a></td>
<td height="166">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Flash on iOS ? You can have the same efect with CSS and :hover .

Comment: basically if you go to the site on the ipad the menus don't work because they're flash menus and the ipad doesn't seem to support flash so i'd like to create a menu similar to the one on the website but so that it'll work on the ipad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ipad doesnt support flash. However you can recreate them with HTML and Css...

Make pictures out of them and make a menu with css :

**CSS**

```
.ul li.menu1 a { 
  display:block;
  width:20px; 
  height:20px; 
  background-image:url('image.png');
}
.ul li.menu1 a:hover { 
  background-image:url('imagehover.png'); 
}

.ul li.menu2 a { 
   display:block;
   width:20px; 
   height:20px; 
   background-image:url('image2.png');
}
.ul li.menu2 a:hover { 
   background-image:url('image2hover.png'); 
}
```

**HTML**

```
<ul>
  <li class="menu1"><a href="#"></a></li>
  <li class="menu2"><a href="#"></a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I've changed the menu so that it works now without using flash. The problem now is that when you hover over the link, it highlights the whole text and you can't read the text (mainly because of the colour of the highlight. Is there anyway to remove the highlighting from the links? I forgot to add the link to the new menu http://www.gmbelt.com/index.html

Comment: everything you add in the a:hover will effect. for highlight i suppose you mean the line under the text... you can remove that by useing text-decoration:none; in the a:hover class.

Comment: Ah i see what you mean... That is a background-color. remove the background-color class in the a:hover

Comment: No I don't mean the line under the text. What I mean is when you move the mouse cursor over the link it highlights the link when I don't want it to.

Comment: Cheers, that's fixed the problem. I'll mark this as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

iOS doesn't support Flash. For top menu , simple css commands like this enough

```
.a{background-image:url('bg.gif');}
.a:hover{background-image:url('bg_hover.gif');}
```

for left menu you can look here : http://www.htmldrive.net/items/show/1074/Vertical-Accordion-effect-with-jQuery-